# display json array in table

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, jqgrid

guys i am trying to display json using online library .. but only the table appears without items .. here is my code

```
[{"OrderID":"1","CustomerID":"WILMK","OrderDate":"1996-07-04 00:00:00","Freight":"32.3800","ShipName":"Vins et alcools Chevalier"},
          {"OrderID":"2","CustomerID":"TRADH","OrderDate":"1996-07-05 00:00:00","Freight":"11.6100","ShipName":null},
          {"OrderID":"3","CustomerID":"HANAR","OrderDate":"1996-07-08 00:00:00","Freight":"65.8300","ShipName":"Hanari Carnes"}];
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: "index.jsp",
            colModel: [
                { label: 'OrderID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },
                { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 150 },
                { label: 'Order Date', name: 'OrderDate', width: 150 },
                { label: 'Freight', name: 'Freight', width: 150 },
                { label:'Ship Name', name: 'ShipName', width: 150 }
            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 780,
            height: 250,
            rowNum: 20,
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
    });
```

Comment: Well, you've defined the `rows` array, but where do you use it?

Comment: @MysterX please see the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JQGrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), you would do it like this:

```
var rows= [{"OrderID":"1","CustomerID":"WILMK","OrderDate":"1996-07-04 00:00:00","Freight":"32.3800","ShipName":"Vins et alcools Chevalier"},
          {"OrderID":"2","CustomerID":"TRADH","OrderDate":"1996-07-05 00:00:00","Freight":"11.6100","ShipName":null},
          {"OrderID":"3","CustomerID":"HANAR","OrderDate":"1996-07-08 00:00:00","Freight":"65.8300","ShipName":"Hanari Carnes"}];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "index.jsp",
        colModel: [
            { label: 'OrderID', name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },
            { label: 'Customer ID', name: 'CustomerID', width: 150 },
            { label: 'Order Date', name: 'OrderDate', width: 150 },
            { label: 'Freight', name: 'Freight', width: 150 },
            { label:'Ship Name', name: 'ShipName', width: 150 }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 780,
        height: 250,
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });
    for (var i= 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("addRowData", i+1, rows[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: still no data appears

Comment: where is that documenattaion plz

Comment: I have not used jqGrid, so I can't provide much other info.  I just read the docs.  The link to the docs is in my answer, just click "JQGrid docs".